# Activating Anaconda on VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

After installing Anaconda and run my code VS code, I got the following in my terminal.
But why would my terminal executes the code first instead of activating the virtual environment? Is it a bug and how can I fix it?

```
C:\Users\test>python -u "c:\Users\test\quickSort.py"
[1, 2, 4, 5]

C:\Users\test>C:/Users/Me/anaconda3/Scripts/activate

(base) C:\Users\test>conda activate base

(base) C:\Users\test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, that program is executed from your system default python path.
which is `C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python[version]\`

later you activated the Conda environment. which will also run the same python program but from another path.

It's not a bug. It's a feature.
You can't fix it. You should adapt it

Both of them will run your python program. It's good for managing packages.

Comment: I set the path to the one in anaconda.

Comment: Yeah mate, there are 2 paths. One in your system default and the other in your conda path. Both of them will run your python program. The thing is Conda will make it easy for you to manage the packages.

Comment: I didn't activated the conda environment myself. I just click the run button in vscode and then it happens. The order is bit weird as you can see from my question above. Is it normal?

Comment: Your first input was ``python -u "c:\Users\test\quickSort.py"`` and here VSCode used the default python path. which is normal and also happened to me a lot.

Comment: It's my responsibility to help my fellow programmer, Have a nice day!